# Dual monitor flickering in Ubuntu 12.04 with ATI

Tags: 12.04, ati, multiple-monitors, flicker

This question might have been asked before but the solution posted there don't work for me. I have a laptop with the usual VGA output for a second monitor. On Windows I had no problem with connecting the second monitor but on Ubuntu 12.04 when I do it they start flickering like hell and I can't do anything (click, drag, open windows).
I have installed the ATI driver (by following these instructions: [Installing the AMD/ATI Catalyst drivers for 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/126513#126513)) and everything goes well on the laptop's monitor.

I don't know if it is the driver or the system. I tried this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375425/dual-monitor-problems-screen-flicker-and-offset) and several *xrandr* changes but it doesn't work. My card is AMD Radeon HD 7600M series and the second monitor is a 19" Acer.

I can't believe that at this stage we have this kind of issues with something that should work without problems. Sticking to Ubuntu is a great challenge for me every day.

Answer (score 3):

For those who my encounter this problem: you have to execute the commands after you connect the second monitor. Type them before, connect and when the flicker starts press ENTER. Remember:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --left-of LVDS1 --output VGA1 --auto --scale 1.0001x1.0001
```

or

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --right-of LVDS1 --output VGA1 --auto --scale 1.0001x1.0001
```

Comment: God bless you! It works for me after, maybe, 6 hours!