# Extended Desktop broken into 4 halves on 2 monitors

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors, display, radeon

I'm having this issue on my **HP Envy 17-2070nr** with a **Radeon HD 6850M**. I'm using **Ubuntu 14.04**.

Here's info. for anyone who can help:

- Extended desktop causes internal monitor to show 1/2 of its own monitor and
  1/2 of the external monitor's screen with a vertical separation (left
  and right halves).
- The other 2 halves are shown on the external monitor.
- Each screen (internal and external) works fine independently.
- Mirrored mode (both showing the same desktop) works fine.
- Extended desktop also causes non-stop display flickering to
  each monitor.
- Taking a screenshot of the extended desktop shows a normal extended
  desktop with each monitor functioning properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dual Monitor problems - Screen Flicker and Offset](http://askubuntu.com/questions/375425/dual-monitor-problems-screen-flicker-and-offset)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, found a workaround here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2149791.

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto --left-of HDMI1 --output HDMI1 --auto --scale 1.0001x1.0001
```

(Adjust outputs accordingly)
The important thing is to change the scale of your output. Beats me why this works, I hope they'll come up with a proper fix.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Could you please explain in a little more detail what this workaround actually does?

Comment: Added a little info, but I think the workaround was found by trial and error.